# developing videofiles browser in android

Tags: android, file, video, browser

I'am new in Android developing. I need to create videofiles browser, videofiles must be displayed as thumbnails, supporting up-down sliding. From what should I start? Thanks, waiting for your comments..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution of your problem.

```
   public class EntertainmentActivity extends Activity {

      private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String( "/mnt/sdcard/VideoFolder");

        static String[] fileList = null;
        GridView gridView;
        static String FILE_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/VideoFolder/";
        String MiME_TYPE = "video/mp4";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            updateSongList();
            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            File dir = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            if (dir.exists()) {

            } else {
             dir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (fileList != null) {
                gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, fileList));
            }
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                    String videoFilePath = FILE_PATH + fileList[position];
                    System.out.println("******************************videoFilePath****************" + videoFilePath);

                    System.out.println("******************************MiME_TYPE****************"+ MiME_TYPE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), MiME_TYPE);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        public void updateSongList() {
            File videoFiles = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            Log.d("*********Value of videoFiles******", videoFiles.toString());

            if (videoFiles.isDirectory()) {
                fileList = videoFiles.list();
            }
            if (fileList == null) {
                System.out.println("File doesnot exit");
                Toast.makeText(this, "There is no file please add files to "+MEDIA_PATH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("fileList****************" + fileList);
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    Log.e("Video:" + i + " File name", fileList[i]);

                }
            }

        }
```

GridView Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private final String[] VideoValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] VideoValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.VideoValues = VideoValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("***********IngetView************");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from gridlayout.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(EntertainmentActivity.fileList[position]);
            System.out.println("value of fileList[position]" + EntertainmentActivity.fileList[0]);
            // set image
            ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            Bitmap bmThumbnail;

            System.out
                    .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> file path>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                            + EntertainmentActivity.fileList[position]);

            bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils
                    .createVideoThumbnail(EntertainmentActivity.FILE_PATH + EntertainmentActivity.fileList[position],
                            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            if (bmThumbnail != null) {
                System.out
                        .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>NO THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // return 0;
        return VideoValues.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

main.xml Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff99cc00" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

grid_row.xml Row Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#92d050"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="test string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

don't forget to put user-permission in AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```